# Divs: Equal Horizontal Spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a site that has a series of four images on the homepage used as navigation with a large image beneath.

```
<div style="width: 696px">
<div class="imglink"></div>
<div class="imglink"></div>
<div class="imglink"></div>
<div class="imglink"></div>
</div>

<div style="width:696px">
...
</div>
```

The "imglink" divs are 160px wide.

I would like the images in the top div to be horizontally spaced evenly inside the div, with the two outer divs flush with the edges of the image below. I've been trying out floats, margins, padding, etc for a couple hours now and can't figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the first and last divs distinct.

```
<div class="imglink_first"></div>
<div class="imglink"></div>
<div class="imglink"></div>
<div class="imglink_last"></div>
```

Then your css could apply margin only to `imglink`.

Your total padding would be `696px - 4*160px = 696px - 640px = 56px`. There are three padding regions, so each should be `56px/3 = 18.67px`. Unfortunately this is not an integer, so you need to round. `18px * 3 = 54px` leaving two extra pixels at the end of your div. Also, you will need `18px/2 = 9px` per left and right side.

```
.imglink_first, .imglink, .imglink_last{
   float: left;
}

.imglink{
  margin: 0px 9px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use CSS selectors with `:first-child` and `:last-child`

```
<div class="image-row" style="width: 696px">
   <div class="imglink"></div>
   <div class="imglink"></div>
   <div class="imglink"></div>
   <div class="imglink"></div>
</div>

.imglink{
   float: left;
   margin: 0px 9px;
}

.image-row:first-child, .image-row:last-child{
   margin: 0px;
}
```

Though this is not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a jumping off point for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/gqf5h/1/

Answer (score 3):

If you know the number of menu items, wrap each one in a div. Then set your menu div widths to a percentage of the width and set text-align center. ie

for 4 menu options :

css

```
#menu div{
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<div id='menu'>
  <div><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div><a href='#'>link</a></div>
</div>
```